# Скрыть отображение label если поля заполнены

Tags: html, jquery

В данный момент ошибка остается если заполнить второе поле, и нажать на кнопку, а нужно чтобы не отображалась если оба поля заполнены.

```js
$('#buildTree').click(function() {
  if ($('#validOsdch').val() == '') {
    $("#labelErr").text("Введіть об\'єкт!");
    $('#validOsdch').focus();
    $("#labelErr").css("display", "block");
    return;
  } else if ($('#validKiz').val() == '') {
    $("#labelErr").text("Введіть код виробу!");
    $('#validKiz').focus();
    $("#labelErr").css("display", "block");
    return;
  } else
    $("#labelErr").css("display", "none")

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label> Об'єкт </label>
<input type="text" id="validOsdch" placeholder="Позначення" data-field="osdch" autocomplete>

<label> Виріб </label>
<input type="text" id="validKiz" placeholder="Код виробу" data-field="kiz" autocomplete>

<button id='buildTree' class='btn btnCollor btn-sm btn-success'>Клёц</button>
<label style="color: red; margin-top: 15px; display: none;" id="labelErr"></label>
```

Comment: вполне ожидаемо, проверка то написано как если $('#validOsdch').val() == '' в противном случае если $('#validKiz').val() == '' что написали то и получили. меняйте условия

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Попробуйте так:**

```js
$('#buildTree').click(function() {
  if ($('#validOsdch').val() === '') {
    $('#validOsdch').focus();
    $('#labelErr').text('Введіть об\'єкт!').css('display', 'block');
  } else if ($('#validKiz').val() === '') {
    $('#validKiz').focus();
    $('#labelErr').text('Введіть код виробу!').css('display', 'block');
  } else {
    $('#labelErr').text('').css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="lol">Об'єкт</label>
<input type="text" id="validOsdch" placeholder="Позначення" data-field="osdch" autocomplete>

<label>Виріб</label>
<input type="text" id="validKiz" placeholder="Код виробу" data-field="kiz" autocomplete>

<button id='buildTree' class='btn btnCollor btn-sm btn-success'>Клёц</button>
<label style="color: red; margin-top: 15px; display: none;" id="labelErr"></label>
```

Comment: как думаете, мой вариант исправленный в вопросе тоже будет отрабатывать хорошо?

Comment: @Sorpok, да, но можно отрефакторить получше.

Comment: понял, спасибо за ответ, единственное что если пробелы поставить оно пропускает)

Answer (score 2):

Просто ветку else можете добавить, в ней скрывать сообщение об ошибке